# Is there any way to allow TLS renegotation in istio tls options?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

Is there any way to allow TLS renegotation in istio TLSSettings ?
I'm looking into a way to force envoy to setup allow_renegotiation into True
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/auth/cert.proto#auth-upstreamtlscontext

Comment: I'm not sure but have you tried [Istio Envoy Filter](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/envoy-filter/)